# Public or private?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Coursetro {

   string fName;
   uint age;

   function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
   }

   function getInstructor() private constant returns (string, uint) {
       return (fName, age);
   }

}
```

Does it mean that nobody can get or see data from getInstructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables are visible in the network. As for the private function, this means that nobody except the contract itself can call the function.

Hope this helps

Comment: I set variables through setInstructor. If I'm not contract - how can I see values: age, fName, if nobody can call the function?

Comment: You can't access the variables through this contract, you should change the function getInstructor to public or external.

Note that in a more advanced topic you can use web3.eth.getStorageAt() and see the list of variables in your contract, but I guess this is not what you are asking. Just change the function to public

Comment: Sorry. You said "All the variables are visible in the network". Idon't understand,  how can Somebody  see value of 'age' and 'fName' in case when getInstructor is private?   You mean that I can't store passwords or logins in blockchain even if var is private?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Even if you declare the variables as private anyone can see the storage of the contract. The network is public.